# Running AITextGen on Apple Silicon Mac

Tags: macos, pytorch, huggingface, large-language-model

I'm using a MacBook Pro with an M1 chip, and I am having trouble getting aitextgen to recognise its GPU -- it looks for a CUDA GPU, which Apple Silicon Macs don't use.  It works without using the GPU but is of course slower.

Below is the code I ran:

```
# Info on GPT Neo Models: https://huggingface.co/models?other=gpt_neo

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from aitextgen.TokenDataset import TokenDataset 
from aitextgen.tokenizers import train_tokenizer
from aitextgen.utils import GPT2ConfigCPU
from aitextgen import aitextgen


# This code is from Apple and it invokes MPS : https://developer.apple.com/metal/pytorch/

import torch
if torch.backends.mps.is_available():    
   mps_device = torch.device("mps")    
   x = torch.ones(1, device=mps_device)    
   print (x)
else:    
   print ("MPS device not found.")    

ai = aitextgen(model="EleutherAI/gpt-neo-1.3b", to_gpu=True)
```

Below is the output from Python:

> tensor([1.], device='mps:0')Generate config GenerationConfig { 
> "_from_model_config": true,  "bos_token_id": 50256,  "eos_token_id":
> 50256,  "transformers_version": "4.28.1"} loading file vocab.json from
> cache at
> aitextgen/models--EleutherAI--gpt-neo-1.3b/snapshots/8282180b53cba30a1575e49de1530019e5931739/vocab.jsonloading
> file merges.txt from cache at
> aitextgen/models--EleutherAI--gpt-neo-1.3b/snapshots/8282180b53cba30a1575e49de1530019e5931739/merges.txtloading
> file tokenizer.json from cache at Noneloading file added_tokens.json
> from cache at Noneloading file special_tokens_map.json from cache at
> aitextgen/models--EleutherAI--gpt-neo-1.3b/snapshots/8282180b53cba30a1575e49de1530019e5931739/special_tokens_map.json
> loading file tokenizer_config.json from cache at
> aitextgen/models--EleutherAI--gpt-neo-1.3b/snapshots/8282180b53cba30a1575e49de1530019e5931739/tokenizer_config.json
> AssertionError: CUDA is not installed.
>
> > > > 

It looks like aitextgen doesn't support the MPS GPU framework from Apple.  Has anyone had any luck using aitextgen and Huggingface models on an Apple Silicon Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in the code that there's no way to explicitly set an arbitrary device:

https://github.com/minimaxir/aitextgen/blob/master/aitextgen/aitextgen.py

If you want it to work, you could modify the code yourself (and maybe submit a PR to them).

Comment: That is hugely helpful!  Of course this is Python, so the code is a *script* :).  I created a new function but unfortunately couldn't test it by running the aitextgen.py file (it needed additional files including on Google Collab).

However, I raised an issue via Github with proposed changes.
https://github.com/minimaxir/aitextgen/issues/229

Thank you!

Comment: As an update -- Since my last reply, I set up Github Desktop and used this to push an updated version of the file for review.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Hugging Face libraries directly? It's no guarantee that any model will work, but at least you have a shot at it working. I experience that most models require capabilities not implemented in the MPS architecture.

```py
import tempfile
import transformers

model = "EleutherAI/gpt-neo-1.3b"
prompt = "How now brown"

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as offload_folder:
    tokenizer = transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model)
    model = transformers.AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        model,
        device_map="auto",
        offload_folder=offload_folder,
        trust_remote_code=True,
    )
    tensor = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt", return_token_type_ids=False).to(
        model.device
    )
    outputs = model.generate(**tensor)
    results = [tokenizer.decode(output, skip_special_tokens=True) for output in outputs]
    print(results)
```

If you get any MPS errors, simply the "to" device to "cpu".

This:

```py
    tensor = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt", return_token_type_ids=False).to(
        model.device
    )
```

Becomes:

```py
    tensor = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt", return_token_type_ids=False).to(
        "cpu"
    )
```

I tested the running the model with my example on my Intel Mac, and it ran fine on the CPU.

Comment: I haven't tried that!  I will have a go.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).